# Secret keys in SCM

Tags: security, wp-config, deployment

I have a WordPress installation in a Git repository and I'm wondering, if it's safe to have the [8 "secret keys"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Security_Keys) stored in there, or if I should insert them during deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config file shouldn't be public at all. It includes your database credentials in addition to the 8 SALTs WordPress. (The secret keys alone make it possible to brute force your log-in in a bout a week: http://codeseekah.com/2012/04/09/why-wordpress-authentication-unique-keys-and-salts-are-important/)

Comment: It also prevents portability, the test instance may not have the same DB details etc

Comment: Great, thanks for the him, Stephen! I'll replace the salts like the database credentials during deploy with Capistrano.